# to increase and decrease value inside textview on button click on particular position

Tags: android, listview

I want to increment and decrement values inside textview on click of button at particular position.I have made custom listview.Problem is that when i click on + button of first item, qty increase by 1 and prize increases by 20 but when i click on second item the quantity increases directly from 0 to 2  and prize increases directly to 40.I want Book must get increased by 20,pen must get increased by 30 and pencil by 5 and same is for decrement.As I am new in android plz help me.Thanks for your help in advance.Following is my code:-

```
order.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/item_name"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sr_no"

       >
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/srno"
           android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
           android:text="ITEM NAME"
           android:id="@+id/itemname"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:textColor="#000"
           />

   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/qtity"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_name"

       >
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="40dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemname"
           android:layout_below="@+id/lunch"
           android:text="QTY"
           android:id="@+id/quantity"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:textColor="#000"
           />

   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qtity"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/snacks"
            android:text="PRICE"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sr_no"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="SR.NO"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/srno"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/listdetails"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>


customlist.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/i_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/s_no"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/i_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/plus1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/pl"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/minus1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/pr"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/min"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pl" />
</RelativeLayout>


Order.java
public class Order extends Activity {

    ListView list_item;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order);

        list_item=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listdetails);

        int sr[]={1,2,3};
       // int sr=1;
      //  String[] item_name={"book","pen","notebook","pendrive","rubber","scale","pencil","slate","crayons","compass box"};
        String [] itemname={"book","pen","pencil"};
        int [] quantity={0,0,0};
        //int[] price={20,20,25,25,30,30,20,10,25,10};
        int [] price={20,30,5};



            Custom_Adapter ca=new Custom_Adapter(this,sr,itemname,price,quantity);
            list_item.setAdapter(ca);
    }
}


CustomAdapter.java
public class Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity a;
   int sr [];
int quantity[];

    String itemname[];
    int price[];

    TextView qt;
    public static int count=0,count2=0,cal;


    private String data,pricedata;



    public Custom_Adapter(Activity a, int[] sr, String[] itemname, int[] price, int quantity[]) {
        this.a = a;
        this.sr = sr;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemname.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class viewHolder{

        TextView srh,item,qt,rate;
        Button plus,minus;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final viewHolder viewHolder=new viewHolder();
        LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
        View view=li.inflate(R.layout.customlist,parent,false);
        viewHolder.srh=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.s_no);
        viewHolder.item=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.i_name);
        viewHolder.qt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        viewHolder.plus=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.pl);
        viewHolder.minus=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.min);
        viewHolder.rate=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pr);




        viewHolder.srh.setText(Integer.toString(sr[position]));
        viewHolder.item.setText(itemname[position]);
        viewHolder.qt.setText(Integer.toString(quantity[position]));

        viewHolder.rate.setText(Integer.toString(price[position]));





        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                   count+=1;
                count2+=20;
                viewHolder.qt.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                viewHolder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(count2));



            }
        });
        viewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (count>0 && count2>0) {
                    count = count - 1;
                    count2-=20;
                    viewHolder.qt.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    viewHolder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(count2));
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, the more code you share the more clear will be your question. 

What data should be displayed? Your list should contain single viewType or different kinds? How do you update data?

Comment: above code which i have posted  is full ..i want to increase or decrease the amount and quantity at particular item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understood your code logic is not correct.first you get which item you have selected according to that maintain your quantity[] array if you have selected book from list update your count on quantity [1,0,0] and if again you select book so fist get value of book quantity count increment on it by 1 and update quantity [2,0,0].

Comment: Can  you tell me  correct logic?as you said for book is correct but at same time pencil quantity and its amount should get increased and decreased

Comment: Ok sure and wait for sometime i will rewrite your problem in better way give m some time :)

Comment: Hi i have fixed your problem i have done some few modification on custom adapter you can download code from below link thanks enjoy :)  https://bitbucket.org/nikhoney27/penpencils

Answer (score 0):

As far your question is concerned the problem is in your java code not in xml , so if you post your java code we can help you

The problem might be you might have been reusing your model object throughout your listview dataset

Comment: Create a model class and put the count value inside that model class , use that class to set or get the count so that for each item you have a separate entry

Class Model {
String sr;
String itemname;
 int[] price, int quantity[]) {

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your java code in your listview u have button on each row and textview also if yes you have to declare your integer in adapter if its out side of listview then you may declare it in your main class. I think your have same variable for each listview item just initialize an integer inside your adapter it will solve the issue. You may show your java code for further help. Hope you get it what i want to say and it may help you.Best of Luck buddy !

Comment: can you give solution

Comment: you have to show code buddy . After that I may help you

Comment: Oh my bad I skipped from last let me check it I will let u know if I can help you with this mate.

Comment: First of all remove static from public static int count=0,count2=0,cal;

Comment: Second use Arrayadapter instead of base adapter of class and make class for each element avoid sending arraylists of int and strings. This is making things complex

Comment: First of all initialize counts in get view instead of adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Model {
        int sr;
        String itemName;
        float price;
        float singlePiecePrice;
        int quantity;

        public Model(int sr, String itemName, float singlePiecePrice, int quantity) {
            this.sr = sr;
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.singlePiecePrice = singlePiecePrice;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
    }


    public class Order extends Activity {

        ListView list_item;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.order);

            list_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdetails);

            ArrayList<Model> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
            dataSet.add(new Model(1, "book", 0, 20));
            dataSet.add(new Model(2, "pen", 0, 30));
            dataSet.add(new Model(3, "pencil", 0, 5));

            Custom_Adapter ca = new Custom_Adapter(this, dataSet);
            list_item.setAdapter(ca);
        }
    }


    public class Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private ArrayList<Model> dataSet;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public Custom_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> dataSet) {
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.dataSet = dataSet;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dataSet.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Model model = dataSet.get(position);
                        model.quantity++;
                        model.price += model.singlePiecePrice;
                        dataSet.set(position, model);
                        holder.qt.setText(String.valueOf(model.quantity));
                        holder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(model.price));


                    }
                });
                holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Model model = dataSet.get(position);
                        if (model.quantity > 0 && model.price > 0) {
                            model.quantity--;
                            model.price -= model.singlePiecePrice;
                            dataSet.set(position, model);
                            holder.qt.setText(String.valueOf(model.quantity));
                            holder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(model.price));
                        }

                    }
                });


            }

            return convertView;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {

            TextView srh, item, qt, rate;
            Button plus, minus;
        }

    }
```